# SQLITE request syntax error

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sqlite

I have an issue with a request, it works fine with pgsql and mysql, but with sqlite, it seems like I am missing something

here is the request :

```
select * from mesure_insitu 
where (id_formulaire, gid) IN (
  select distinct id_formulaire, max(gid) as gid 
  from mesure_insitu 
  where id_dispo_comp_ouvr = 1 
  GROUP BY id_formulaire 
  ORDER BY id_formulaire ASC
)
```

This subquery below works fine:

```
select distinct id_formulaire, max(gid) as gid 
from mesure_insitu 
where id_dispo_comp_ouvr = 1 
GROUP BY id_formulaire 
ORDER BY id_formulaire ASC)
```

I think the problem is with the condition with two values `(id_formulaire, gid)`, like sqlite cannot use a condition with two values.

I will appreciate any type of help.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. `.dump` from SQLite command line tool for a suitably tailored toy database is very convenient.

Comment: "_Row values were added to SQLite version 3.15.0 (2016-10-14)._" [Link](https://sqlite.org/rowvalue.html#backwards_compatibility)

Comment: @Abelisto you are right, do you know how to upgrade my database to become 3.15 ?

Answer (score 2):

To get this query to work, update your SQLite to a [newer version](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html).

If you cannot do this, you have to use a join instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM mesure_insitu
JOIN (SELECT id_formulaire, max(gid) AS gid 
      FROM mesure_insitu 
      WHERE id_dispo_comp_ouvr = 1 
      GROUP BY id_formulaire)
USING (id_formulaire, gid);
```

(The DISTINCT and ORDER BY are superfluous in this subquery.)

Comment: BTW `JOIN` could to multiply rows. IMO the better alternative is `EXISTS`.

Comment: @Abelisto With GROUP BY (or DISTINCT), rows are unique.